# I'm trying to use Selenium webdriver in Pycharm, can you use it in your project or only Python console?

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I have succesfully installed it and it works fine in the Python Console but when i try to import it to the project with 
`from selenium import webdriver`

it gives me an error and says it cannot be imported.
Sorry, i'm new to Python, i don't even know if its supposed to only be used in the console or not.

Comment: What "project" are you importing into? One in Eclipse, Pycharm, Visual Studio, etc.? What error are you getting? `webdriver` is just a python package and can be used in any python file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to check the "Inherit global site-packages" option when you create the project.

[image]

If that doesn't work, please post the actual error so we can understand better your problem.

Comment: This solved it. Thanks. I decided to not post the error because it literally read what i said," cannot import name 'webdriver' from 'selenium'."